# jom.exe return witd exitcode 2 and a lot of Boost warnings

Tags: c++, qt, boost

i have QT 5.1 with the beta 5.2 moc.exe because otherwise i get the boost error. I am using VS 2012 compiler but with 2010 is is the same. If i run my program i get 8000 boost 1.55 Macro warnings and then

```
C:/includes/boost/mpl/remove.hpp(48): Warning: Macro argument mismatch.
C:/includes/boost/mpl/remove.hpp(48): Warning: Macro argument mismatch.
C:/includes/boost/mpl/bitand.hpp(24): Parse error at "("
jom: C:\Users\Documents\QT\build-QtCoverage-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_32bit-Release\Makefile.Release [release\moc_parameter.cpp] Error 1
jom: C:\Users\Documents\QT\build-QtCoverage-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_32bit-Release\Makefile.Release [release\moc_mainwindow.cpp] Error 1
jom: C:\Users\Documents\QT\build-QtCoverage-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_32bit-Release\Makefile [release] Error 2
11:05:45: Der Prozess "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" wurde mit dem Rückgabewert 2 beendet.
Fehler beim Erstellen/Deployment des Projekts QtCoverage(Kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.1 MSVC2012 32bit)
Bei der Ausführung von Schritt 'Make'
```

I search a lot but i have no idea. I can run programs test programs or part of this projects but when i run the whole project i get this error ...

The problem is also that i get 8000 warnings of boost Macro so it is possible that i oversee something important. How i can deactivate this ?

And anyone has an idea what i can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known incompatibility between Qt moc and boost. The known work around is to guard the boost includes.

The relevant bug reports:
https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6687

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-22829

And the workaround:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/pull-request/14/fix-for-qt-bug-22829/diff

Comment: hello, thank you for your help. But is this problem not solved if i use QT 5.2 beta moc.exe?

Comment: and where i find the include/sdf/Param.hh file?